# Java BufferedReader.readLine() not waiting for user input

Tags: java, user-input

I am having an issue with my instance of BufferedReader not waiting for the user to input before moving forward.

```java
static BufferedReader in;

public class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input;
            System.out.println("prompt");
            input = in.readLine();
            if(input.equals("Y")){
                //do something
            }else {
                //do something else
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is I when I run the program, it simply skips over the in.readLine() and throws a null exception at the if statement. I am at a loss on what is happening, as I used the same code for another project that still works.

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me. BTW, how does your code compile? You're missing `throws IOException`.  Or is this not actually your complete code?

Comment: Sorry yeah I omitted the try/catch blocks

Comment: Primary rule, ALWAYS include the actual code that compiles, via copy/paste, do not retype your code.  You are ignoring an exception.  Put something in the `catch` block to print the stack trace.

Comment: Added it how I have it now.

Comment: And how do you provide the user input? And is the environment you're using expected to accept the input in that way?

Comment: @Tom Not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: How and where do you run your code and how and where do you provide user input.

Comment: Sorry, turns out my gradle environment wasn't parameterized properly. Was missing a standardInput = System.in. Haven't really used something like gradle before. Didn't know that was a required statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Using gradle to run the program and my task didn't have the parameter for standardInput = System.in. Still getting used to project building software!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to treat the exception, just add this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input;
        System.out.println("prompt");
        input = in.readLine();
        if(input.equals("Y")){
            System.out.println("it works !!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("it's not a Y :(");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I had omitted it initially but added it how I have it now.

Comment: please elaborate or provide the complete code or situation.